# flask error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'password'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

```py
class Register(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'register'
    register_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    occupation = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    dateofbirth = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    contact = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    email_id = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
```

this is login function

```py
@app.route("/login",methods=['GET','POST'])
def login_post():
    email = request.form.get('email')
    password = request.form.get('pass')
    user = Register.query.filter_by(email_id=email).first()
    print("password",password)
    print("email",email)
    print(user.password)
    if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
    login_user(user)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html')
```

this is error

```
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in 
    handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request() 
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in 
    full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in 
    handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in 
    full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in 
    dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    File "C:\Users\dhruv\Desktop\Farmer\Main.py", line 46, in login_post
    print(user.password)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'password'
```

how to solve it? I was creating login authentication where this line `user = Register.query.filter_by(email_id=email).first()` is giving me this error. what is the issue here?
is this because of browser cookies? or anything with python version? I am using python 3.7 latest version and coding in pycharm on localhost

Comment: [`Query.first()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first) returns the first row, _or_ `None` if there are no results. `user = Register.query.filter_by(email_id=email).first()` is returning `None`, so it's the same as executing `None.password`. You need to work out why your query isn't returning a record, most likely there is no user in the database with the specified email.

Comment: user is present with specified email id in database. i have checked it manually by writing "user = Register.query.filter_by(email_id='info@example.com').first()" and 'info@example.com' is present in database

Comment: If `print(user.password)` raises `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'password'`, then `user` _is_ `None`, and that will only occur if the query doesn't match any records. Try inspecting the value of the email that is submitted from the form.

Comment: when I use Register to enter the details in the sign-up form then using the same table my database is updating but when I want to check the details by the same table for authentication with same email it is giving me an error

Comment: Are you using wtf_forms?

Comment: Nop not wtf_forms

Answer (score -1):

First, check whether your models are perfect and make sure you have at least one record in the user table.

Then delete browser cookies and try.

If you are still facing the same issue try this :

Go to `flask-user package > usermixin.py` and change the following code.

Line Before :

```
user_password = '' if user_manager.USER_ENABLE_AUTH0 or user == None else user.password[-8:]
```

Line After :

```
user_password = '' if user_manager.USER_ENABLE_AUTH0 else user.password[-8:]
```

Comment: No need for this: This was [discussed](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/issues/238#issuecomment-724574637) in the flask-user repo on GitHub but I suggest that if that line is in your installed flask-user it means that you have a relatively old version installed. Update/refresh your flask-user version instead to include improvements that make this suggestion redundant.